# Typesafe action creators in redux

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I've failed countless times forgetting to extract connected action creator from props like this:

```
import {actionCreator} from 'my-actions';
interface Props {
  actionCreator: typeof (actionCreator);
}

const Foo: React.SFC<Props> = (props) => {
  // oh, i forgot to take actionCreator from props
  // const { actionCreator } = props; 

  return (<Button 
    onClick={actionCreator} // Santa, I wish it would fail to compile this, can you make it throw an error?
  />); 
} 

export const mapDispatch = (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>) => {
  return bindActionCreators({
     actionCreator,
  }, dispatch);
}

export const ConnectedFoo = connect(null, mapDispatch)
```

The above will silently compile, but you will not see any action in redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you imported `actionCreator`, so it is visible in the whole module, therefore you get no compile error.

Possible solutions:

1.) Put the container component and the presentational component into two separate files: the `import`, `mapDispatch` and `ConnectedFoo` would be in *connected_foo.ts* and `Props` as well as `Foo` would be in *foo.tsx* and then you get a compile error.

2.) `Foo` should not have a property with the name `actionCreator`, a better name would be `action` or maybe `onClick` -- you do not give action creators to presentational components, but actual actions.

Comment: Hey, thanks, but I am looking for a single file scope-shadowing solution.

Comment: You know, after a second thought, I think strict `onSomething` naming convention for bound action creators solves this problem. Cheers!